# What is the fastest way to create a pandas sub table/dataframe based on values of the primary dataframe and able to search in both?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm struggeling to create a pandas sub dataframe based on values of the primary dataframe. The primary dataframe, that will contain over millions of row, is set up as follow:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def get_range(start, stop, step):
    return np.linspace(start, stop, int((stop - start) / step) + 1)

range1 = get_range(10, 10, 10)
range2 = get_range(10, 100, 10)
range3 = get_range(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
range4 = get_range(7, 100, 1)
range5 = get_range(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
range6 = get_range(0.2, 2.0, 0.01)
range7 = get_range(0.2, 2.0, 0.01)

df = pd.DataFrame(
    index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
        [
          range1,
          range2,
          range3,
          range4,
          range5,
          range6,
          range7,
        ],
        names=["col1", "col2", "col3", "col4", "col5", "col6", "col7"]
    )
  ).reset_index()
```

The above results in the following dataframe (30M+ rows), which is created super fast in about ~5/6 sec:

```
          col1   col2  col3   col4  col5  col6  col7
0         10.0   10.0   1.0    7.0   1.0   0.2  0.20
1         10.0   10.0   1.0    7.0   1.0   0.2  0.21
2         10.0   10.0   1.0    7.0   1.0   0.2  0.22
3         10.0   10.0   1.0    7.0   1.0   0.2  0.23
4         10.0   10.0   1.0    7.0   1.0   0.2  0.24
...        ...    ...   ...    ...   ...   ...   ...
30795335  10.0  100.0   1.0  100.0   1.0   2.0  1.96
30795336  10.0  100.0   1.0  100.0   1.0   2.0  1.97
30795337  10.0  100.0   1.0  100.0   1.0   2.0  1.98
30795338  10.0  100.0   1.0  100.0   1.0   2.0  1.99
30795339  10.0  100.0   1.0  100.0   1.0   2.0  2.00
```

Now, based on these values, I want to calculate a new table that wil have the number of rows given in 'col4'. So for every row the table is dynamically created. Below is given the function that will create the table with all the value I need. In this function I will calculate only one value, becuase if I understand the solution I want, I can complete the whole table by myself.

```
def calculate_table(col4, col5, col6):
    table = []
    prev_value = 0
    for msotc in range(1, col4+1, 1):
        
        max_value = (prev_value * col6) + col5
        if max_value < 100:
            table.append(max_value)
        else:
            table.append("*")
        prev_value = max_value
    return table
```

So eg. with the following values from the primary dataframe:

```
col4 = 7
col5 = 1
col6 = 2
```

The calculated table will be:

```
[0, 1, 3, 7, 15, 31, 63, '*']

          t_col1  t_col2  t_col3   etc.     
0         0.0   
1         1.0
2         3.0
3         7.0
4         15.0
5         31.0
6         63.0
7         0
```

So after the caculation for every row, the result can be adde to eg. 'col8', I want to be able to search something like:

eg. Select every row where ['col8']['t_col1'] > 30 and ['col2'] > 50

Which will result is a the selection on the primary dataframe.

Because of the huge amount of rows where the calculation has to take place for the sub table/dataframe, I'm really looking for the fastest way to have the calculation take place. So maybe the function needs to be rewritten to be as fast as possible and also the way to apply the function on every row is importent.

Comment: So what part do you need help with: writing a faster `calculate_table` function or the searching after?

Comment: I want to search afterwards. So the 'calculate_table' needs to be applied on every row and afterwards I want to search in the complete dataframe (primary and sub). But I can imagine that the function can be rewriten to make it faster. This becuase the calculated table is always based on the number of rows given in 'col4' + 1.

Comment: Ok... what does `['col8']['col1']` mean, first element of `col8`? Will you make use of every element in `col8` in searches?

Comment: I don't know if it I explained it in a clear way, but the calculate_table will result is col4 number of rows and finally a x number of columns. So my thought was to have that complete table put in the extra column 'col8'. So when search I need to use values from primaray eg.col1, col2, col3 etc, but also search in 'col8' (colums and rows), 'Col8' is presenting the table created with the function.